# How can I convert an AVI file to a Blackberry-compatible format?

Tags: video, conversion, format, convert, blackberry

I need a program to convert an AVI file to a format compatible with my Blackberry. On Windows, I've tried format factory and converted the .avi file to .3gp, but the output is of very bad quality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [**Avidemux**](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux). It also provides good editing features.

[image]

---

**[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)** is another option, only for video conversions. As the app site says:

> WinFF is a GUI for the command line video converter, FFMPEG. It will convert most any video file that FFmpeg will convert. WinFF does multiple files in multiple formats at one time. You can for example convert mpeg's, flv's, and mov's, all into avi's all at once. WinFF is available for Windows 95, 98 , ME, NT, XP, VISTA, and Debian, Ubuntu, Redhat based GNU/Linux distributions.

ffmpeg is really powerful but it might be tricky to use for many users. WinFF provides a GUI for it and makes it easier to use.

[image]

---

**Edit**:

**[Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm)** is another good option.

Application descriptions:

> The Mobile Media Converter is a free video and audio converter for converting between popular desktop media formats like MP3, Windows Media Audio (wma), Ogg Vorbis Audio (ogg), Wave Audio (wav), MPEG video, AVI, Windows Media Video (wmv), Flash Video (flv), QuickTime Video (mov) and commonly used mobile devices/phones formats like AMR audio (amr) and 3GP video. iPod/iPhone and PSP compatible MP4 video are supported. Moreover, you can remove and add new formats or devices through the internet.
>
> An integrated YoutTube downloader is available for direct downloading and converting to any of these formats. You can trim your clips for ringtone creation or any other purpose and crop your videos for removing up/down black bars or other unwanted parts of the image. Additionally, embedded subtitles can be encoded onto the video for watching movies or shows with subtitles on devices that does not supports them.
>
> The program has a very easy-to-use and simple GUI (Graphical User Interface) that helps even the most amateur user. Most of the times, the only data that you must enter is the input file(s) or just drag 'n' drop the input file(s)! The 3GP and AMR formats are used by mobile phones for MMS, video and sound recordings, etc.

[image]

Comment: i cant seem to find a way to convert the avi into any video format using winff.when i select blackberry,the only preset available is mp3(mono).but i need a video.

Comment: What video formats does it support?

Comment: I mean your blackberry.

Comment: it supports 3gp

Comment: I updated the answer.Please try Mobile Media Converter. P.S: Please remove my answer as best answer and just vote it up until you get your answer.I'll lose the reputation but it may help to find better answers.Some users which know the answer won't open the question when it's answered.

Comment: it works :)i made it the answer again.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

**Convert AVI to 3gp using ffmpeg**

**ffmpeg** is an excellent application on video conversion. It supports most of the file formats.

```
ffmpeg [[infile options][-i infile]]… {[outfile options] outfile}…
```

**Convert from MPG to 3GP**

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mpg -s qcif -vcodec h263 -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 32 -y outputfile.3gp
```

**Convert from AVI to 3GP**

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -s qcif -vcodec h263 -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 32 -y outputfile.3gp
```

**Convert from 3GP to AVI**

```
ffmpeg -i clip.3gp -f avi -vcodec xvid -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 file.avi
```